# Problem in JQuery UI Accordion usage

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

I am trying to use JQuery Accordion, however I am facing a difficulty in writing the code.

```
 <div id="accordion">
    <h3><a href="#" id="first">First header</a></h3>
    <div id="first_content">First content</div>
    <h3><a href="#" id="second">Second header</a></h3>
    <div id="second_content">Second content</div>
</div>
```

I want to change the content of the div below the first heading when the user clicks the heading, however I am not able to understand that how I should write the binding function and what else to mention in the accordion function

```
$( "#accordion" ).accordion({
   change: function(event, ui) { what to write in here }
});

$( "#accordion" ).bind( "accordionchange", function(event, ui) {
  what to write in here
});
```

Supposing the HTML content to be replaced with is present in

```
var html = '<h1>Accordion Usage</h1>';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/):

```
$('.ui-accordion').bind('accordionchange', function(event, ui) {
  ui.newHeader // jQuery object, activated header
  ui.oldHeader // jQuery object, previous header
  ui.newContent // jQuery object, activated content
  ui.oldContent // jQuery object, previous content
});
```

So you can use the jQuery functions to replace the element content:

```
$( "#accordion" ).bind( "accordionchange", function(event, ui) {
    ui.newHeader.html("<h1>Accordion Usage</h1>");
});
```

or you can supply the callback at initialization:

```
$( "#accordion" ).accordion({
    change: function(event, ui) { ui.newHeader.html("<h1>Accordion Usage</h1>"); }
});
```

Comment: Although you wouldn't want to put those `<h1>` tags in the header's innerHTML

Comment: So I need to write the following only                                $( "#accordion" ).accordion(); and                                           ui.newHeader.html("<h1>Accordion Usage</h1>");

Comment: You can either supply it with `accordion` or `bind` to an accordionchange event.

Comment: I am using the callback at initialization method but it doesn't seem to work for me, though I am able to see the accordion but nothing happens when I click on the headings..

Comment: Got my mistake.. was using wijaccordion instead of accordion. My bad!!

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.ui-accordion').bind('accordionchange', function(event, ui) {
  $("<div/>", {html : "Hello World"}).appendTo(ui.newContent);
});
```